# Security update for docker image on customer's production

Tags: docker, production

Let's say I have the following layers of docker:

1. Os
2. jre
3. application server
4. application.

The customer is running an image containing all the above.
What is the best practice in case there is an urgent security or any other urgent update on one of the layers.

**For example:**
 there is an urgent security update required on the os layer, and the customer can't wait until we finish the entire CI/CD and certify the change by another docker image.

My assumption was to provide the customer an option to update by his own, and update on his local docker repo the image with updated os, and where all the rest remains the same.
It seems to be very demanding request , is there any alternative or any best practices?

Answer (score 1):

General advises would be to make sure the containers you provide are stateless (you can use volumes to store data). This makes the process of updating the images a question of stopping the old containers and starting the updated ones.

Your clients could use [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) on the target containers to apply a quick fix until you provide them with the new image or you can host a link with the new image that they can pull and update themselves.

Outside of that, I don't think there is a standard for this process.

Comment: I think you didn't fully get to my question. It's not a manner of cluster, nor scaling issues. It's just a manner of best practice to urgently update images on run time in customer env. I know there is an option to run some update command through ```docker exec``` and after than to build on the customer local repo, but I wondered if there is any better approach or any known best practices

Comment: That was part of the answer. I did say that the containers you write should be stateless and gave quick fixes in the last paragraph. I'll edit out the extra information.